# SQL date comparison on sql

Tags: android, mysql, sql, date

need help in getting this logic side by side. I am using 3 fields in a table.

```
Select Year, Date, Revenue from Sale
```

The result will be like this

```
Year   Date       Revenue
2014 01/02/2014    500
2013 01/02/2013    250
2014 02/02/2014   750
2013 02/02/2013   250
```

Here is what I need to display

```
2014   01/02/2014  500  2013 01/02/2013  250  
2013   02/02/2014  750  2013 02/02/2013  250
```

The one we need to show should display in 4 columns. I tried some self join but it is cartesian product.  Not sure it works. Please help me with this logic

Comment: what is the criteria- getting revenue ? and 4 columns ok but how will it be 3 fields and 4 columns

Comment: Sorry it should be 6 columns

Answer (score 0):

It seem like Pivot table, and you can try to do like this example :

[Pivot Table](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e22a993f-71e7-42b0-80ec-da70aaa72bd6/display-horizontal-rows-vertically-sql-server-2008-r2?forum=sqlgetstarted)